# Do not open dired for directories when using counsel-find-file

Tags: counsel

I've recently started using spacemacs with ivy, and what drives me nuts is that I instinctively press `RET` when a directory is selected to descend into it, which opens `dired` instead. Is there a way to prevent counsel from doing that and only have `RET` work on files and not directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default (I am not familiar with Spacemacs overrides), Ivy binds `C-m`/`RET` to the command `ivy-done` and `C-j` to `ivy-alt-done`. As described [in the manual](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer), the difference is that the former ends the completion session with the currently selected candidate, whereas the latter enters a directory in the case of filename completion. See also the manual section on [filename completion](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#file-name-completion).

I have personally become accustomed to this distinction and use the default keybinding for `ivy-alt-done` most of the time. If you tend to instinctively go for the `RET` key (i.e. `ivy-done`), however, and don't rely on the `ivy-alt-done` binding as much, I would recommend swapping the bindings of the two commands:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'counsel
  (let ((done (where-is-internal #'ivy-done     ivy-minibuffer-map t))
        (alt  (where-is-internal #'ivy-alt-done ivy-minibuffer-map t)))
    (define-key counsel-find-file-map done #'ivy-alt-done)
    (define-key counsel-find-file-map alt  #'ivy-done)))
```

You can replace `counsel-find-file-map` with `ivy-minibuffer-map` if you want the swap to apply to all `ivy`-completed commands, not just `counsel-find-file`.

You can also replace `(where-is-internal <cmd> ivy-minibuffer-map t)` with whichever keybinding you prefer, otherwise this returns the default `ivy` binding for the given `<cmd>`.